# Why does python in a conda environment take so much longer to tokenize a file?

Tags: python, conda, nltk

The script I am trying to run is:

```
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')

print('starting')

# Get tokens
with open('passage-collection.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    text = f.read()
    print('read text')
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

print('ever reach here?')
```

In an environment not managed by conda, it runs in a minute.
In a conda environment, I have been waiting for 20 minutes and it has still not finished running.

Output:

```
scripts>python task1.py
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
starting
read text
```

*hangs*

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, using different machines.

Have also verified that it is a 'speed' issue. Although the 60MB file I am trying to tokenise has not completed yet, a dummy file with 5 words completes just fine.

Comment: `conda` is a package/environment manager, not a Python runtime. What exactly do you mean by running a Python script "with conda". What *exactly* are you doing?

Comment: so I am simply running 'python script.py' inside an environment. I have now tried it on a completely different machine same issue. Weirdly, running a python 'benchmarking' script shows similar performance, but this above code snippet refuses to run. 30+ mins waited. Perhaps a strange interaction with nltk but not sure how it hasn't been reported before.

Comment: It's odd that the version used by the conda environment takes so much longer, but it would help to localize the problem. Did you try to isolate the problem to nltk? For example, try separating the `f.read()` from the `word_tokenize()` call and then printing something before you open the file, right after you open the file, after you read the file, and after you pass it to `word_tokenize`.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to [edit] your post and to include the actual [mcve]: if someone else starts with nothing, what do they need to do to reproduce the problem  you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have updated the question. I have also tried the suggestion by @PranavHosangadi, no change. I have reverted to using venv and everything works smoothly, though, the issue still bugs me.

Comment: Do you see some of the printed statements? Or do you see none of them? That can help narrow down which part takes too long to execute?

Comment: Yes, I see 'starting' and 'read text' and then nothing

Answer (score 0):

Something is taking a long time. You didn't spell out what,
and you didn't tell us what OS you're running this on.
I am going to assume ubuntu linux.

Please augment your source code in this way:

```
from time import time

print("Starting.")
t0 = time()

import nltk
print(time() - t0)

nltk.download('punkt')
print(time() - t0)
```

Then focus on unblocking the part that shows high delay.

Another ad hoc technique is to insert a `breakpoint()` near the top
and keep typing "n" next, next, next, until you hit the statement that hangs.
Or use "s" step to dive into the troublesome function call.

If `text` is "too big",
successively cut it in half until we see reasonable timings.
That will reveal clues about the underlying Root Cause.

Comment: Apologies, have tested on both Catalina and WIN10. Have also updated question clarifying that it is specifically the tokenisation that hangs.